# Make an element with set size responsive to parent element

Tags: css, responsive

I have an element on my page that will show an iPhone and screenshots within it. The phone and screens are set at the actual pixels so that real screenshots can be used within the element.

```
.iphone
    .iphone__outer {
        width: 416px;
        height: 850px;
        background: asset-url("iphone6-portrait.png") center center no-repeat;
        background-size: 416px 850px;
        position: relative;
        .iphone__inner {
            background: #ffffff;
            position: absolute;
            top: 86px;
            left: 20px;
            width: 375px;
            height: 667px;
        }
    }
}
```

However I'm wanting to make this element responsive. If I make the `.iphone__outer` just 100% then it will prevent me from positioning the screens correctly. How can I make an element with nested positioned absolute element responsive to its parent?

One idea I had was to use images for everything and then position them using percentages and remove the height. That way when the browser scales it would resize them accordingly and the height would be work fine. However I'm wanting to animate the images that are inside the `.iphone__inner` so therefore I need to set an overflow hidden on it and that would mean specifying a height which means I can't do it this way.

My current solution is to make the element smaller using scale when on a certain breakpoint:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .iphone {
        width: 208px;
        height: 425px;
        .iphone__outer {
            transform: scale(.5);
            transform-origin: left top;
        }
    }
}
```

But I was hoping to avoid having to set it to a certain size using scale for the different breakpoints. As it means that it will be a set size and not using all available space. And instead I'd like to have it scale automatically based on the parent element. e.g. the iPhone will be displayed inside a grid system.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/mL5rpn5k/3/

And example of the HTML might be:

```
<div class="iphone">
  <div class="iphone__outer">
    <div class="iphone__inner">

<img src="screen1.png">
<img src="screen2.png">
<img src="screen3.png">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of hard time making sense of this. The inner should it scale with the outer `iphone`? Inner shoulden't it be 100% of the `iphone` if it should show screens? Isn't it better to have the parent to adjust to the inner screen image?

Comment: It should all scale yes. See the fiddle for an example of what I do.

Comment: so the inner should be a image (jpg, png...)?

Comment: No as the inner will contain multiple images.

Comment: Ok but still the inner will contain `<img>` (jpg, png...)?

Comment: Yes the inner is the screen itself and will have all elements I want to show on the iphone.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mL5rpn5k/10/)?

Comment: @Huelfe Yes! How did you work out the percentages?

Comment: Tried a little bit with developer tools. :)

Comment: Sound. Well you should post it as an answer as it's a very close solution. However I have noticed that at certain sizes it is ever so slightly out...

Comment: @Huelfe I wonder if it's possible to work out what the ACTUAL percentages should be?

Comment: yeah it is possible. See your image has 416px width. at 20px your screen beginns. -> 20*100/416 = 4.80769%...

Comment: Awesome. `top: 10.1176470588%; left: 4.80769%; right: 4.80769%; bottom: 11.4117647059%;` is all I needed!

Comment: @Huelfe You should post your solution as an answer so I can accept it as it works perfectly once I worked out the rest of the maths!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with aspect ratio. Let's have a look:

SCSS:

```
.iphone__outer {
  width: 416px;
  height: 850px;
  background: url("//image.ibb.co/ktWBMS/iphone6_portrait.png") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 416px 850px;
  position: relative;
  .iphone__inner {
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 86px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 375px;
    height: 667px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
  .iphone__outer {
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 196%;
    width: auto;
    background: url("//image.ibb.co/ktWBMS/iphone6_portrait.png") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    .iphone__inner {
      background: #ffffff;
      position: absolute;
      top: (100%*86/850);
      left: (100%*20/416);
      width: (100%-((100%*20/416)*2));
      height: (100%-((100%*86/850)*2));
      right: (100%*20/416);
      bottom: (100%*86/850);
    }
  }
}
```

Also notice that SCSS can actually calculate your needed percentages as you can see above.

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL5rpn5k/18/).

Comment: The padding bottom also needs working out: `padding-bottom: ( 850px / 416px * 100% );`

Comment: Thanks again for the solution. It works perfectly! Didn't know you could do maths in SCSS as well. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i completely understand what you mean. But if you only want the element to have the same aspect ratio while being able to resize, you can use `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` with percentages. The pixel amount when using percentages for padding is always calculated from the width instead of height: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

Comment: Yes I thought of using aspect ratios... but what would the padding be in this scenario? Considering that it's not going to be the standard 4:3, 16:9 etc. and that the inner element is needed to be positioned absolute.